# Is Django 1.3 alpha available in pypi yet?

Tags: python, django

I have a buildout script that gets django as a dependency. I'd like to play with Django 1.3 in my project, but I don't want to download and install it, I'd like my buildout to do that.

Does anyone know how I can do this, or am I better off just downloading from the website and placing django in the appropriate spot?

UPDATE:
I got this to work by changing the following in the setup.py file

```
setup(
    install_requires = ('django=1.3-alpha-1',),
    dependency_links = ('http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3-alpha-1/tarball/#egg=django-1.3-alpha-1',),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you wait for django to be released in PyPI or you include it with your packaging solution.

**Edit**: If you want buildout to do it all for you, you can use the [url attribute](http://www.buildout.org/docs/tutorial.html#custom-egg-building) and let it download the package from the django website.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to use the url attribute as you suggest and also get the version I want.  my setup.py file has this setup(install_requires='django==1.3', **other_args)

Comment: I made the following changes and got it to work. In setup.py: install_requires=('django==1.3-alpha-1',)  and dependency_links=('http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.3-alpha-1/tarball/#egg=django-1.3-alpha-1',).  Now it works. Thanks!